# Installing mysqlclient for mariadb on mac os for python3

Tags: python, django, macos, python-3.x, mariadb

I have an issue with processing for the `pip install mysqlclient` for Python3 on MAC OS Sierra.

```
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.6
clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/include -Dversion_info=(1,3,10,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.10 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.2.6/include/mysql -I/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.2.6/include/mysql/.. -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.6/_mysql.o
_mysql.c:1911:42: error: no member named 'reconnect' in 'struct st_mysql'
        if ( reconnect != -1 ) self->connection.reconnect = reconnect;
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I have installed MariaDB and `xcode-select --install` and also processed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is here since `mariadb` *10.2.x*, with `mariadb` *10.1.23* I have no problem to install `mysqlclient`.

So with `mariadb` *10.2.x* we needs to install `mariadb-connector-c`:

```
brew unlink mariadb

brew install mariadb-connector-c
ln -s /usr/local/opt/mariadb-connector-c/bin/mariadb_config /usr/local/bin/mysql_config

pip install mysqlclient

rm /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
brew unlink mariadb-connector-c
brew link mariadb
```

UPDATE: the bug is fixed in mysqlclient (see https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/pull/177) but not yet released

Comment: Would be intressting to know why or what they removed from mariadb 10.2.X

Comment: I think is related to this line of the changelog : Old GPL client library is gone; now MariaDB Server comes with the LGPL Connector/C client library (MDEV-9055)

Comment: The problem itself is, that applications (like Python) shouldn't touch internals of MYSQL or MYSQL_STMT structures, especially if there are API functions available.

MySQL added in 2004 the option MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT to change the reconnect behavior via mysql_options() call - so maybe it's time now to fix it.

Comment: It seems that is now fixed : https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/pull/177

Comment: Yes that problem fixed and this solution also working, thank you for the help!

Comment: Seems fixed in mysqlclient, but not yet released

Comment: Thanks for this, was the only way I could get mariadb and flask work on macOS.

Comment: How to do it with centos

Comment: And now (July 2018) it seems that this no longer works with `mariadb-connector-c` version `3.x`. If that is the case other folks as well, I made a brew tap for version `2.2.2`: https://github.com/frnhr/homebrew-mariadb-connector-c-2/blob/master/Formula/mariadb-connector-c.rb , simply `brew install frnhr/homebrew-mariadb-connector-c-2/mariadb-connector-c`

Answer (score 9):

SOLVE:

```
pip uninstall mysqlclient
pip install -U git+git://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python
```

Comment: sweet and short